# what is animationTimingFunction in vivus.js

Tags: javascript, svg

I was just going through the source of vivus.js and came across the followng like of code:

```
  currentFrame = this.animTimingFunction(this.currentFrame / this.frameLength) * this.frameLength;
```

Now this function call can be seen **[HERE](https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus/blob/master/src/vivus.js#L384)**.

The only other place this is defined in is below:

```
  this.animTimingFunction = options.animTimingFunction || Vivus.LINEAR;
```

This can be seen on the repo **[HERE](http://%20%20this.animTimingFunction%20=%20options.animTimingFunction%20%7C%7C%20Vivus.LINEAR;)**.

Now my question is , why is `this.animTimingFunction` being called as a function when it actually is not a function ? can anybody explain ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But [it is a function as mentioned in the code comments](https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus/blob/master/src/vivus.js#L25)

> animTimingFunction `<function>` timing animation function for the complete SVG`

From the code it is one of the options that can be passed to the Vivus constructor. Predefined timing functions are defined at [line 66](https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus/blob/master/src/vivus.js#L66)

> ```
> /**
>  * Timing functions
>  ************************************** 
>  * 
>  * Default functions to help developers.
>  * It always take a number as parameter (between 0 to 1) then
>  * return a number (between 0 and 1)
>  */
> Vivus.LINEAR          = function (x) {return x;};
> Vivus.EASE            = function (x) {return -Math.cos(x * Math.PI) / 2 + 0.5;};
> Vivus.EASE_OUT        = function (x) {return 1 - Math.pow(1-x, 3);};
> Vivus.EASE_IN         = function (x) {return Math.pow(x, 3);};
> Vivus.EASE_OUT_BOUNCE = function (x) {
>   var base = -Math.cos(x * (0.5 * Math.PI)) + 1,
>     rate = Math.pow(base,1.5),
>     rateR = Math.pow(1 - x, 2),
>     progress = -Math.abs(Math.cos(rate * (2.5 * Math.PI) )) + 1;
>   return (1- rateR) + (progress * rateR);
> };
> ```

On [line 204](https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus/blob/master/src/vivus.js#L204)

> ```
> this.animTimingFunction = options.animTimingFunction || Vivus.LINEAR;
> ```

you can see that it either uses the passed function or when nothing is set for `animTimingFunction` a default function defined at `Vivus.LINEAR`

So you can not pass a function, pass one of the predefined functions, or pass your own timing function:

```
Vivus(...,{},...);

//OR
Vivus(...,{
   animTimingFunction:Vivus.EASE
},...);

//OR
Vivus(...,{
   animTimingFunction:Vivus.EASE_OUT
},...);

//OR
Vivus(...,{
   //custom function
   //input number between 0 and 1
   //output number between 0 and 1
   animTimingFunction:function(x){
       //manipulate x as needed and return the new number
   }
},...);
```